# Select duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have data like this :

```
| col1 |
--------
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  1   |
|  2   |
```

How can I get like this and order by MAX to Min :

```
| col1 |
--------
|  2   |
|  1   |
```

I try this :

```
SELECT col1 , count(col1 ) FROM myTable GROUP BY col1
```

But I got strange results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order by the count of occurences of each value:

```
SELECT col1, count(1) FROM myTable GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY count(1) DESC
```

If you want to order by the actual value contained in `col1`

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM myTable ORDER BY col1 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL `DISTINCT` keyword to only show unique results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM myTable;
```

You can then order by that column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM myTable ORDER BY col1 DESC;
```

Comment: Good code but I needn't to him, answer 2 is my ultimate goal :)